# Pagination links with a locale prefix in URLs Grails

Tags: grails, pagination, url-mapping

If you're using language prefix in URL mappings such as

```
/$lang/$controller/$action?/$id?
```

and the URLs you are generating contain parameters in addition to the lang parameter, you'll get the following URL, for an additional param such as offset:

```
/book/list?offset=10&lang=en
```

but this breaks my mappings. Instead, I want the URL to look like this:

```
/en/book/list?offset=10
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the following bean (assuming that your lang param is called "lang"):

```
class LangAwareUrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean extends UrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean {

    @Override
    public UrlMappingsHolder getObject() throws Exception {
        def obj = super.object
        obj.DEFAULT_CONTROLLER_PARAMS = [UrlMapping.CONTROLLER, UrlMapping.ACTION,     "lang"] as Set
        obj
    }   
}
```

And adjust the *resources.groovy*:

```
"org.grails.internal.URL_MAPPINGS_HOLDER"(LangAwareUrlMappingsHolderFactoryBean) { bean ->
    bean.lazyInit = true
}
```

And you'll get

```
/en/book/list?offset=10
```

instead of

```
/book/list?offset=10&lang=en
```